# How to do flaten a date sequence in snowflake given the 'unnest' code in Athena SQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sequence, amazon-athena, unnest

I am just learning Snowflake. Now having a problem which is probably about unnest/flaten etc. I have a SQL code in Athena:

```
SELECT
    CAST(a2 AS DATE) dates
FROM
    (VALUES
        (SEQUENCE(CAST(FROM_ISO8601_DATE('2022-01-01') as timestamp),
                CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as timestamp),
                INTERVAL '1' day)
        )
    ) AS t1(a1)
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(a1) AS t2(a2);
```

The results is a date sequence:
[image]

How can I do this in Snowflake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
WITH GAPLESS_ROW_NUMBERS AS(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY seq4()) - 1 as "ROW_NUMBER" 
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(rowcount => 400))) -- 400 OR 400000 BOTH WORK FAST

SELECT DATEADD('DAY', ROW_NUMBER,'2022-01-01')::DATE as DATE --YOU CAN ADJUST '2022-01-01'
FROM GAPLESS_ROW_NUMBERS 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2022-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE();
```